How to create a dynamic max range based on highest value?
i have got question regarding in power bi about making the x axis range dynamic based on the highest value in each individual bars?
This is the measure that i have created below that gets the max value range and sets the same range for each bars according to the highest values
Max Total Inload =
CALCULATE(
MAXX(
VALUES(fact_InloadAct[t Train Dump]),
[Total Inload]
)
)
but the result doesnt seem to be correct it shows the range upto 200k while the high value is 31.9k so the range should be at 31k as shown below
enter image description here
below is an example diagram that i have done
for example if the highest value is 50k then the range will automatically become 50 k for each bars range as shown below
enter image description here
and if the highest value is 39.1k  then the range will automatically become 39 k for each bars range as shown below
enter image description here
The end result i am expecting to see is having the same x axis range for each individual bars based on the highest value as shown below
enter image description here

This is the sample data I used for test



t Train Dump
Inload




a
100


b
200


c
300


a
300



Then you create measures
Total Inload = sum(fact_InloadAct[Inload])

Measure = maxx(all(fact_InloadAct[t Train Dump]),[Total Inload])

Then in the settings, you find the maximum range for X-axis. Click the fx button

select the measure we just created


